# Insert/replace text in SSRS report using MDX

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, mdx, ssrs-2012

i am running a MDX in my DATASET in SSRS Report. The MDX is

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY 
 (
 {
 ([Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Income], [Dim Account].[Account Summary].[Account Summary])
    ,([Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Income], [Dim Account].[Account Summary].[All])
    }
    )
    ON ROWS
    FROM [CubeProfitLoss];
```

After running this MDX i am getting the following result in SQL Server Result Pane

[image]

But when i add this MDX code in my Dataset and run the report i am getting every thing same except 'ALL' it is not shown up and i am actually i don't want to show 'ALL' instead of this i am happy to insert/replace 'TOTAL' in that place. Is anyone have that stuff? I always appreciate any king of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH MEMBER 
[Dim Account].[Account Summary].TOTAL AS
[Dim Account].[Account Summary].[All]

SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY 
  [Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Income] 
  * 
  {
   [Dim Account].[Account Summary].[Account Summary].MEMBERS
   +
   [Dim Account].[Account Summary].TOTAL
  }  ON ROWS
    FROM [CubeProfitLoss];
```

Comment: Not only Awesome you are, legend as well ! Thanks a lot. it worked perfectly as per my expectation.